# Linq query taking too long to process results

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have 3 tables

- ERPEntry
- ERPEntryType
- ERPApp

I am trying to get data from these 3 tables using the below queries:.. The table ERPApp is in different context than the other 2 tables, that is the reason i am using 2 queries

```
var res = (from s in ERPDB.ERPEntrys
         join t in ERPDB.ERPEntryTypes
         on s.EntryTypeID equals t.EntryTypeID
         where s.UserIDAdded == '250176'
         select new {s.EntryTypeID, s.DateAdded, t.EntryTypeName, s.AppID }).OrderByDescending(d => d.DateAdded).Take(10).ToArray();

var erpResult = (from a in APPDB.ERPApps.AsEnumerable()
         join b in res on a.AppId equals b.AppId
         select new ERPInfo
         {
          EntryId = b.EntryID,
          EntryType = b.EntryTypeName,
          ERPApp = a.ApplicationName,
          DateAdded = b.DateAdded
         }).ToList();
```

I got the desired result but the 2nd query is taking almost 4 minutes to process and return result into varibale erpResult... any help on how can i resolve this performace issue ?

Comment: By doing `APPDB.ERPApps.AsEnumerable()` you load up the entire table in your C# application and move through every row. That's the reason it's taking long.

Comment: `.AsEnumerable()` is it needed there? Can you try without it and see if you have an issue?

Comment: How many records does `APPDB.ERPApps` have? Because in your second query, I see that `APPDB.ERPApps` is a lookup table because you only use the `ApplicationName` field out of it. If this lookup is what you need this table for, there can be other ways to achieve this. (And I still don't know why it takes 4 minutes, even if there are millions of rows)

Comment: Something else to try is set up logging for EF and see what query(s) is being generated. You might be missing an index in the database.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception

Comment: @DragandDrop yeah, without .AsEnumerable() i got this error 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context' .... That is the reason for using AsEnumerable()

Comment: @404 without .AsEnumerable() i got this error 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context' .... That is the reason for using AsEnumerable()

Comment: @OguzOzgul there are 25,000 rows APPDB.ERPApps table.. i need to get AppName from this table for the AppId i got in the 1st query

Comment: Isn't res an array of only 10 records?

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes its an array of only 10 records

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem by using a table of 86.000 rows. It completes in seconds. Does your `APPDB.ERPApps table `have any BLOB columns? How many columns does it have?

Comment: @OguzOzgul my table has 173 columns in it..

Comment: @OguzOzgul do we have any better way of writing above query ?? the only solution i see is loop through result 'res' and get AppId, query APPDB.ERPApps table and get AppName based on the AppId and build the collection for IEnumerable collection for ERPInfo

Comment: I will try to post a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the answer:

```
var res = (from s in ERPDB.ERPEntries
join t in ERPDB.ERPEntryTypes
on s.EntryTypeID equals t.EntryTypeID
where s.UserIdAdded == "250176"
select new { s.EntryID, s.EntryTypeID, s.DateAdded, t.EntryTypeName, s.AppId })
.OrderByDescending(d => d.DateAdded).Take(10).ToArray();

/* Which immediately executes:

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[EntryID], [t0].[EntryTypeID], 
[t0].[DateAdded], [t1].[EntryTypeName], [t0].[AppId]
FROM [dbo].[ERPEntry] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ERPEntryType] AS [t1] ON [t0].[EntryTypeID] = [t1]. 
[EntryTypeID]
WHERE [t0].[UserIdAdded] = @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[DateAdded] DESC',N'@p0 varchar(8000)',@p0='250176'

*/

// Get the distinct AppID values in res
// Executes in memory
var distinctApps = (from r in res select r.AppId).Distinct();

// Query APPDB with the distinct values
var matchingApps = (from a in APPDB.ERPApps where distinctApps
.Contains(a.AppId) select new { a.AppId, a.ApplicationName }).ToArray();

/* Which immediately executes this efficient query:

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[AppId], [t0].[ApplicationName]
FROM [dbo].[ERPApp] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[AppId] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3)',N'@p0 bigint,@p1 bigint,@p2 
bigint,@p3 bigint',@p0=101,@p1=123,@p2=125,@p3=129

*/ 
var erpResultWithAppNames = (from a in matchingApps
join b in res on a.AppId equals b.AppId
select new
{
EntryId = b.EntryID,
EntryType = b.EntryTypeName,
ERPApp = a.ApplicationName,
DateAdded = b.DateAdded
}).ToList();
```

Extra notes:

As already mentioned in the comments, the call to `.AsEnumerable()` on the `APPDB.ERPApps` table causes the whole table to be loaded into memory as objects.

Facts:

1. You had to load 25.000 rows into memory (and convert them to objects),
2. You are not only loading 25.000 rows. You are loading 25.000 x 173 cells and create 25.000 objects with 173 fields each.
3. if you could just load the two fields you need (AppId and ApplicationName) instead of all the 173 fields (with whatever data they have) the performance would improve, but would still be inefficient considering what you are trying to achieve.
4. The current performance problem is in part due to transferring the whole table with all its 173 fields to your server, and in part to mapping all these rows to objects and fields to properties. The impact of each can be measured as further research.

Linq To SQL. When checked with SqlProfiler:

```
from a in APPDB.ERPApps.AsEnumerable() join b ...

// PROFILED QUERY:
SELECT [t0].[AppId], [t0].[ApplicationName], [t0].[Field1], [t0].[Field2],
[t0].[Field3], [t0].[Field4], [t0].[Field5], [t0].[Field6], [t0].[Field7],
[t0].[Field8], [t0].[Field9], ... ... ... ... [t0].[Field176], [t0].[Field173],
FROM [dbo].[ERPApp] AS [t0]
```

But:

```
var erpResult = (from a in APPDB.ERPApps
select new { AppId = a.AppId, ApplicationName = a.ApplicationName }
).ToArray();

// PROFILED QUERY:

SELECT [t0].[AppId], [t0].[ApplicationName]
FROM [dbo].[ERPApp] AS [t0]
```